# UINavigationBar Change Font

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to change the font on my NavigationBar throughout my app. I have created a subclass for the UINavigationViewController.

I am able to build and run the code, but when I launch the app, it freezes and the error is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

My code is below:

```
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 236/255, green: 28/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "ITCFranklinGothicStd", size:12)!]
```

The bar color and text bar work fine, but I can't get the font to change. It is located in the override viewdidload section of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ITCFranklinGothicStd` must not be a valid font name, so your UIFont becomes nil and your `!` tries to unwrap it. --> crash.

Try replacing `ITCFranklinGothicStd` with a known valid font name like `HelveticaNeue-Light` and you'll see it works.  Then go out and find the valid name.  If it's a custom font then one way to do this is to open the font in Font Book and view the Font Info.

Comment: You were right, I was referencing the custom font wrong. Forgot to add the -med at the end. Really appreciate the help!